# eclipse is not starting in ubuntu and it is stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I have installed eclipse using the command `sudo apt-get install eclipse`, then i have added Java EE plugin by following the steps given in this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/81341/install-eclipse-ide-for-java-ee-dev-via-apt-get-is-it-possible

I created a project in eclipse and it worked for 2 days without any issues. Suddenly today wen I am trying to start the eclipse I am getting the screen to select a workspace, when I selected my workspace then the eclipse is showing in dull color and it is not starting even after waiting for a long time. I am using eclipse 3.8 version.

Below are details from my `eclipse.ini` file

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```

I have set the heap memory minimum as 1GB and maximium as 2GB but still I am facing same issue.

If I try to select a different workspace then the eclipse is loading fine. Please help me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: I think you should ask this question at the SuperUser Stack Exchange website. Not here!

Comment: Thanks Afzaal, can you please share the link for SuperUser site